# How to create 2 shopping cart rule in magento 1.9.3.2

Tags: discount, rules

We are selling dress where with different **Category A and B**. Category A need to give buy 2 or more to get **15% Off**. Category B is flat **10% off** on all products. If people buy Category A 1 product and Category B 1 Product, the discount is 10%, but it takes 15%. Can you guide me pls?

Comment: Which Magento version?

Answer (score 3):

It would be great if you provide more information about your rules (priority etc).

Rule 1 (15%) example screenshot https://goo.gl/ohGFFY

Rule 2 (10%) example screenshot https://goo.gl/MwA3ZY

If these rules are applied, and user buy Category A 1 product and Category B 1 Product, the discount is 10%
https://goo.gl/xZrzdM